# Make an alterable/editable html table from javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Hi I am having trouble figuring out how to make my rows editable

Html:

```
  <body>
      <div>
        <button>Get</button>
        <div id="table"></div>
      </div>
        
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
```

I have a participant that i will want to also alter when i alter the html table

Javascript related to the participant:

```
     function Participant(id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    }

var participantArray = []; 

//Used to get data from xml into the Participant and then add him to the array

   var xpartic = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("participant");
   for (i = 0; i < xpartic.length; i++) {
    participanttxt += "Participant - " + "Id: " + xpartic.item(i).getAttribute("id") + " Name: " + xpartic.item(i).getAttribute("name") + "\n" ;
    var novo = new Participant(xpartic.item(i).getAttribute("id"),xpartic.item(i).getAttribute("name"));
    
    this.addtoArray = function(){
          participantArray.push(novo)
    }();
    }
   console.log(participantArray);
```

Javascript related to the table:
I dont know how to allow for the rows to be editable

```
let btnGet = document.querySelector('button');


   let myTable = document.querySelector('#table');



// criação das tabelas

let headers = ['ID', 'NAME'];

btnGet.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let table = document.createElement('table');
  let headerRow = document.createElement('tr');

  headers.forEach(headerText => {
      let header = document.createElement('th');
      let textNode = document.createTextNode(headerText);
      header.appendChild(textNode);
      headerRow.appendChild(header);
  });

  table.appendChild(headerRow);

  participantArray.forEach(emp => {
      let row = document.createElement('tr');

      Object.values(emp).forEach(text => {
          let cell = document.createElement("td");
          let textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
          cell.appendChild(textNode);
          row.appendChild(cell);
      })

      table.appendChild(row);
  });

  myTable.appendChild(table);
});
```

This generates the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JmYF.jpg

I wanted to be able to alter these rows and then do something like this to the array

```
onTableAlter(){
    for(...){
    if(altered.id==participant.id){
    participant.name=altered.name
    }
    }
}
```

When that table is altered.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Here is a great alternative to creating your own table. Check out DataTables, you can style almost however you would like, and you are able to edit rows by initializing this option: https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().edit()

Comment: Unfortunately from what I am seeing, it looks like you need to pay to use the editing.>
A shame since I was liking it alot.